# Invalid controller specified (admin) - Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, routes

I have discovered Zend Framework since a week now and am able to develop a light shopping website. I am now facing an issue : one route gets me an `Invalid controller specified (admin)` error.
This link...

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('id' => $brand->getId()), 'adminDelBrand');?>">
    <span class="supprimer">Supprimer</span>
</a>
```

...which is related to this route...

```
routes.adminDelBrand.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.adminDelBrand.route = "admin/delete/brand/:id"
routes.adminDelBrand.defaults.module = "Cart"
routes.adminDelBrand.defaults.controller = "Admin"
routes.adminDelBrand.defaults.action = "delbrand"
routes.adminDelBrand.defaults.id = 0
routes.adminDelBrand.reqs.id = \d{1,5}}
```

...throws the `Invalid controller specified (admin)` error.

My `delbrandAction()` in the `Cart_AdminController` is the following:

```
class Cart_AdminController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

// more actions...

public function delbrandAction()
{
    $brandMap = new Cart_Model_Mapper_Brand();
    $brand = $brandMap->find($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
    $error = 'success';
    $message = 'La marque « '.$brand->getName().' » bien été supprimée';
    try {
        $brandMap->delete($brand);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $message = 'Erreur : la marque « '.$brand->getName().' » n\'a pas pu être supprimée';
        $error = 'error';
        $this->_helper->bounce(array('b' => $brand->getId()));
    } 

    $this->_helper->toast($message, $error);

    $host = 'http://localhost';
    $this->_redirect($host.$this->view->url(array(), 'adminIndex'));

}
}
```

Do you have any idea what's going on here?

Many thanks.

### Edit:

I have the same schema of action for deleting a category and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: You sure you need the `Cart_` part in the name of your `Cart_AdminController` class?

Comment: Seems like `adminDelBrand` route did not match, so the default route was used.
1) Does resulting id fit `\d{1,5}}`?
2) Do you have your module enabled (referenced in `application.ini`)?

Comment: @i-- > Pretty sure yes :)
@maxivanov > Many thanks for pointing out my mistake at `d{1,5}}` (one braket too many).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from the double closing bracket at the end of `routes.adminDelBrand.reqs.id = \d{1,5}}`.